Can a TypeScript value assertion be made async?
I want to encapsulate the following logic into a helper function:
if (!response.ok) {
  throw Error(await response.text());
}

so that it can read as:
await myAssert(response.ok, async () => await response.text());

But I can't figure out the right TypeScript syntax. If I do this:
async function myAssert(
  precondition: boolean,
  messageMaker: () => Promise<string | Error>
): asserts precondition
{
  const message = precondition ? "-unused-" : await messageMaker();
  assert(precondition, message);
}

then the TypeScript compiler complains:

The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type.

But if I do this:
async function myAssert(
  precondition: boolean,
  messageMaker: () => Promise<string | Error>
): Promise<void>
{
  const message = precondition ? "-unused-" : await messageMaker();
  assert(precondition, message);
}

then in the calling code the TypeScript compiler doesn't understand that response.ok must always be true after awaiting the assertion.
Is there a way I can have both in TypeScript?

No, this is a missing feature of TS requested at microsoft/Typescript#37681. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

User-defined type guards cannot currently be asynchronous. That said, it seems to me like you're seeking an abstraction to unwrap an error (message?) before throwing in reaction to a failed assertion. If that's the case… then perhaps something like this would be useful: https://tsplay.dev/Nlo3rw

Thanks to both of you! @jcalz that 37681 issue looks like exactly what I'm bumping into just didn't have the right vocab to track it down. So probably the clearest way to handle this is just as my initial code rather than trying to come up with an async version of node.js's own assert.

It is not currently possible in TypeScript for an assertion function to be async. There's an open feature request for this at microsoft/TypeScript#37681, but for now this is not supported.
The best you can do is to refactor so that the entire state you care about is returned by the async function. But that will turn out to be a mess if you want it to be general. You might get away with passing in a custom type guard function and assert its results:
async function myAssert<T, U extends T>(
  state: T & (Exclude<T, U> | U),
  predicate: (t: T) => t is U,
  msgMkr: (t: Exclude<T, U>) => Promise<string | Error>
): Promise<U> {
  if (predicate(state)) {
    return state;
  } else {
    const msg = await msgMkr(state);
    throw (typeof msg === "string") ? new Error(msg) : msg;
  }
}

which is currently painful in TypeScript 5.4, but in TypeScript 5.5 we can expect microsoft/TypeScript#57465 to help infer type guard functions. So we could imagine taking something like this
type Resp =
  { success: true, data: string } |
  { success: false, error(): Promise<string> };

async function foo(r: Resp) {
  if (!r.success) { throw new Error(await r.error()) }
  console.log(r.data.toUpperCase());
}
foo({ success: true, data: "abc" }); // ABC
foo({
  success: false, error() { return Promise.resolve("bad") }
}).catch(e => console.log(e)); // bad

and wrapping it with myAssert() as follows:
async function fooWrapped(
  r: Resp
) {
  const goodR = await myAssert(r, r => r.success, r => r.error());
  //  inferred as type guard -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  console.log(goodR.data.toUpperCase());
}
fooWrapped({ success: true, data: "abc" }); // ABC
fooWrapped({
  success: false, error() { return Promise.resolve("bad") }
}).catch(e => console.log(e)); // bad

But it doesn't seem worth it.
Playground link to code
